# toggle button (checkbox) not working on opera mini extreme mode

Tags: html, checkbox, opera-mini

I am trying to add a checkbox based toggle button on my webpage that is compatible with Opera mini extreme data-savings mode. Right now the button does not change its state after it is clicked.

Source of code: https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/
Note that this source when opened on Opera mini extreme mode is working fine.

The button:

```
<div class="onoffswitch" style="display:inline-block;align-items: center;">
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
```

this is the class definition

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 11px;
    background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 11px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 18px; margin: 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 56px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

I thought that maybe the transition property from the class **onoffswitch-switch** style class might not be compatible with OBML but even removing it didn't help. Can you please tell me what changes need to be made so this starts working, or any other form of toggle button that works for Opera Mini Extreme mode.